# When I should use the user model from Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created this class `Person`, but looking at the Django `User` model they seem to be very similar.
In this case, should I be using it ? Or should I keep with my own model ?

My major concern is that, I don't want to my users login into `localhost:8000/admin` page and start to mess with my system and other users data.

```
class Person(models.Model):

    full_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    address = CharField(max_length=255)
    city = CharField(max_length=255)
    country = CharField(max_length=2, choices=CountryChoices, default='')
    gender = CharField(max_length=1, choices=GenderChoices, default='')

    email = EmailField()
    password = CharField(max_length=255)

    started = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    #how it's show in admin
    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.full_name + ' (' + self.email + ')')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *not* create this model. Apart from any considerations of efficiency, it looks as though you are storing passwords in clear text, which is an absolute no.

Instead, extend AbstractBaseUser and set AUTH_USER_MODEL to point to that model. If you define an `is_staff` boolean field, your users will not be permitted to log into the admin site as long as they have that field set to False.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking to give you users access to the admin, there's nothing wrong with using the model that you've included here.

If you wanted to use the auth User model, you certainly could. If you want to add the User model to your model later on, you could tie them together with a ForeignKey.

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong. some of this field are in `User` model. and it is better to use `User` model and define aditional field in your model. take a look at [Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

Also you can develope your own login system like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views).